# UINavigationController:willShowViewController Question

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

I'm confused with this delegate message. I have a navigation controller in a PopupViewController. When I push a new viewController I wan't to know what is the viewController that its being currently displayed, before the new one gets pushed...

I've tried getting navigationController.topViewController & navigationController.visibleViewContrller, but both of them always equal to the viewController that its going to be pushed... It looks like I'm receiving the message **after** the view was pushed

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated{
   UIViewController *currentViewController = navigationController.topViewController;
    if(currentViewController == viewController){
      /// THIS IF STATEMENT IS ALWAYS TRUE 
    }
}
```

Has anyone stumbled upon anything similar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did some digging in the [UINavigationController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and it looks like you can use the [`viewControllers`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006934-CH3-SW16) property of the [`UINavigationController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class.

The root view controller (bottom of the navigation stack) is at index `0` with the with the back view controller (the one that just got covered) at index `n-2` and the [`topViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006934-CH3-SW6) property being at index `n-1` where `n` is the number of view controllers in the array.

As of iOS 7 and Xcode 5.x, you can now send the `firstObject` message to the array returned by the `viewControllers` property to get the root viewcontroller. Similarly, the `topViewController` property can be accessed by sending the `lastObject` message to the array returned by the `viewControllers` property.